# How can I manually update the URI of an entry?

Tags: url

Is there a way to manually change the URI for an entry?
for instance where is this stored in the database (is it?)

I need to update one that is: `/vacancies`  to `/vacancies-1444` for example
the 1444 never got added to the URI when created by an API entry creation and `/vacancies` is the root of a list of vacancies.

Answer (score 1):

For most cases, it should be as simple as updating the slug for that entry to `vacancies-1444` on the entry edit page.

This is assuming it's not in a Structured Section and you haven't defined some custom URI rules where the last segment of the URI isn't `{slug}`.